# Can @Remote turn into @Local?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.1

I'm just wondering under what circumstances would an EJB whose interface is clearly @Remote, end up described in the ejb-merged-jar.xml as ejb-local-ref ?

The case I have is

```
SuperClass
{
   @EJB(name="blah", lookup="blah")
   private Blah1 blah;
}

SubClass extends SuperClass
{
       @EJB(name="blah2", lookup="blah2")
       private Blah2 blah;
}
```

In ejb-merged-jar.xml, in a subclass of SubClass, it says Blah2 is a remote bean, and Blah1 is a local bean.  Incidentally, I am getting NameNotFoundExceptions when it tries to find Blah1.

Ever experienced anything like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the mention of `ejb-jar_merged.xml`, it sounds like you're using WebSphere Application Server.  The product's mapping of `@EJB` to `ejb-ref` or `ejb-local-ref` has had many problems.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.